# How do I get padding to work outside of my iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, padding

I am trying to make padding around my iframe as I need it on a certain position of my webpage but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and googling is confusing me more.
Here's a snippet of my code in my html page:

```
<div class="main" id="main">
  <iframe src="intro.htm" height="500" width="700" padding="200px 200px" title="Iframe Main"></iframe>
</div>
```

I've tried placing the padding in a css under .main, as well as .main iframe{}, but neither worked either.

Answer (score 0):

please use inline style attribute or external css file to add any styles to a web element such as iframe in your case.

```
    <div class="main" id="main">
       <iframe src="intro.htm" style="height:500px; width:700px; padding:200px 200px;" title="Iframe Main"></iframe>
    </div>
```